# Adding a <th> element within a <th> element

Tags: html, html-table

I have an html table with one of the headers spanning over 2 columns. How can I add sub-headers to each of the 2 columns ?

For e.g. in the attached image, I want the 'Contact' column to have sub-headers 'Phone' and 'Address' for the respective columns.

[image]

Comment: +1 all the folks for giving me the right direction. Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The same way you would if you were drawing out the table on paper:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2">Name</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Email</th>
      <th colspan="2">Contact</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Phone</th>
      <th>Address</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <!-- your data goes here -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Adding a new row and then adding sub-headers did work, but they were aligned under 'Name' and 'Email'. So I had to add empty <th> tags in the new row to align the the sub-headers under 'Contact'. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you used `rowspan` and `colspan` in the right places? There should never be any need to add empty cells.

Comment: Ah! Fixed the rowspan on my end and it worked. Thanks once again :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to have two separate header rows:

```
<tr>
  <th rowspan="2">Name</th>
  <th rowspan="2">Email</th>
  <th colspan="2">Contact</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>Number</th>
  <th>Address</th>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add another row and put sub headers in `<td />` tags. Maybe give the row a class and style the td text? That way they won't look identical to the real headers, that might cause confusion.

Answer (score 1):

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>Title 1</th><th>Title 2</th><th colspan="2">Title 3</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>content</td><td>content</td><th>subtitle 1</th><th>subtitle 2</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>content</td><td>content</td><td>content</td><td>content</td>
</tr>
</table>
```